# MethodError: no method matching /(::Int64,::Array{Int64,1}) when generating random numbers based on Normal Distribution in Julia

Tags: arrays, random, julia

I need to construct a multi-element array of random numbers from a normal distribution (using the "Distributions" package for this). I am using the code below.

`[rand(Distributions.Normal(0,a[end]+0.5*(1-b[n])),c,length(b[1,:])*d[n]/c) for n=1:length(b)]`

where (I am using random numbers for this example):

```
a=rand(10)
b=rand(5,32)
c=5
d=collect(1:32)
```

When I run the code I receive the following error message:

> MethodError: no method matching /(::Int64,::Array{Int64,1})

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thank you for your help.

-Alejandro Braun

EDIT:
I changed d to collect(1:32). I had made an error when typing the question, I apologize for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: That error message just means you're trying to divide an integer with an array ... presumably you meant to do the reverse?  Having said that, when I try to run your code above I get an entirely different error message (`no method matching rand(::Distributions.Normal{Float64}, ::Int64, ::Float64)`)  (i.e., you're trying to use a Float instead of an Int when defining the size of the random array you're trying to generate); presumably because julia automatically converts the result of int-by-int division into a float.

Comment: What shape are you trying to get? You can't have a float as one of the dimension sizes?!

Comment: The code does not seem to run in the given form. For example, `d[n]` is a floating point decimal and is multiplying the width of the matrix generated by `rand`.

Comment: I made an edit, sorry for any confusion caused. "d" should have been collect(1:5) rather than rand(5). Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do but if you force the array size to be integers it will give you something (and if you change the size of your array d)... More info?

```
a=rand(10)
b=rand(5,32)
c=5
d=rand(5,32);

[rand(Normal(0,a[end]+0.5*(1-b[n])),c,floor(Int,length(b[1,:])*d[n]/c)) for n=1:length(b)]
```

Comment: Alexander, "floor" was exactly what I was looking for. I made the mistake of saying d was a set of random numbers (it was an error on my part) but your code created the correct array.